# Show that any field is an integral domain

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, solution-verification

I'm trying to show that any field $F$ is an integral domain. So assume that there is some zero-divisor $a \in F$ meaning that for $a \neq 0$ there exists some $b \in F$ with $b \neq 0$ such that $ab = 0$. Can I arrive at a contradiction in the following way, or is there an issue?
$$
\begin{aligned}
ab+a=a\\
a(b+1)=a \\
b+1 = 1\\
b=0
\end{aligned}
$$
Going from one to two holds because of distributivity, two to three holds from left cancellation. Thanks in advance for the clarification.

Comment: Yes, I don't see a flaw there.  You can also get there from $ab=0$ implies that $ab=a0$.  Now cancel the $a$'s.

Comment: You could also just multiply with $a^{-1}$ in the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Left cancellation only works only if in $((ab=ac)\Rightarrow b=c)$, $a$ is not a zero-divisor.

There is a simpler proof, namely that units are not zero-divisors.
Suppose $a,b\in F$ with $a\ne 0$ and $ab=0$.

Then $b = 1b = (a^{-1}a)b = a^{-1}(ab) = a^{-1}0 = 0$. The last step follows since $0$ is absorbing.

Comment: Please strive not to add more (dupe) answers to dupes of FAQs, cf. recent site policy announcement [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/33508/242).